# References to open forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

i am creating a programme where the user enters some data in to the opening form. based on that another window will open. In total i have 4 guis which work on a cyclical basis. You can get from one form to any of the others after a series of different clicks.

Without having to reload some of the forms from scratch (as some have many queries that need to be run) and without having to form1,form2,form3.hide(), form4.show()

how can i do it "properly" :D

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UserControls on one form, instead of working with many forms.
Active control could be easily switched by calling userControl1.BringToFront() method.

Comment: +1  Just want to add that instead of Bring to front have a Panel or any container control and maybe even the form itself and then Remove the Previous Wizard UserControl from control collection and Add the new one to it... A bit clean...

Answer (score 0):

If you always show them in the same order, you can use the Wizard approach, it's also useful if in the future you will add new forms in the middle or in the "edges", usually a wizard application holds somewhere a structure with all relevant data shared from all forms. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No really. Why not:

```
private static Form[] _forms = new Form[] { form1, form2, form3, form4 }; 
public static void ShowForm(Form form) {
    foreach (Form f in _forms)  {
        if (f == form) 
            f.Show(); 
        else 
            f.Hide(); 
    }
}
```